# GWT-RPC Unexplained 500status error when retrieving an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, gwt-rpc

I am developing a GWT client-server webapp using GWT-RPC; mostly it seems to work fine but I am stuck with an error retrieving an ArrayList of an IsSerializable type.

Here is the code for the server-side method:

```
    public GWTInvoiceList listInvoices(String enterpriseID, int selection) {
    try{
        logger.log("ISI getting a listy of invoices "+selection);
        PlataccsUser pxuser =  (PlataccsUser) getSession().getAttribute(PlataccsConstants.USER);
        Enterprise enterprise= pxuser.getEnterprise(enterpriseID);
        Clerk clerk= pxuser.getClerk(enterprise);
         int i=0;
         List<Invoice> invoices =Invoice.getInvoices(enterprise, clerk, selection);
         GWTInvoiceList gwinvoices = new GWTInvoiceList();
         Iterator<Invoice> it = invoices.iterator();
         while (it.hasNext()){
             Invoice invoice = it.next();
             logger.log("ISI-listInvoices converting invoice "+invoice.getSystemInvoiceNumber());
             gwinvoices.add(convert(invoice, clerk));
         }
         logger.log("ISI-lI, the invoice list is now ready and it lists "+gwinvoices.size()+" invoices");
        return gwinvoices;
    }catch(Exception px){
        logger.log("ISI propblem getting invoice list", px);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code executes without throwing any exception. The GWTInvoiceList return type is a simple wrapper for ArrayList and the GWTInvoice type is known to serialize successfully in other calls.  The client side code is:

```
    public InvoiceList(PlataxTabPanel parent, GWTEnterprise gwtEnterprise, int list_selection_type) {
    super(parent, gwtEnterprise.getName());
     topLabel.setText("List of Invoices");
     subHeader.setText("blah blah");
     invoiceService.listInvoices(gwtEnterprise.getEnterpriseID(), list_selection_type, invoiceListCallBack);

     //table headers:
     table.setWidget(0, 0, new ColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_NUMBER_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 1, new ColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_CUSTOMER_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 2, new ColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_VALUE_DATE_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 3, new ColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_DUE_DATE_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 4, new ColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_STATUS_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 5, new MoneyColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_NET_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 6, new MoneyColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_TAX_HEADER));
     table.setWidget(0, 7, new MoneyColumnHeaderLabel(LabelText.LIST_INVOICE_TOTAL_HEADER));

}


final AsyncCallback<GWTInvoiceList> invoiceListCallBack= new AsyncCallback<GWTInvoiceList>(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(GWTInvoiceList invoices){
    Iterator<GWTInvoice> gwit = invoices.iterator();
     int row = 1;
     while(gwit.hasNext()){
         GWTInvoice gwinvoice = gwit.next();
         table.setWidget(row, 0, new Label(gwinvoice.getUserno()));
         table.setWidget(row, 1, new Label(gwinvoice.getCustomer().getName()));
         table.setWidget(row, 2, new Label(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateFormats.SHORT_DATE_FORMAT).format(gwinvoice.getValueDate())));
         table.setWidget(row, 3, new Label(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateFormats.SHORT_DATE_FORMAT).format(gwinvoice.getDueDate())));
         table.setWidget(row, 4, new Label(gwinvoice.getStatus()));
         table.setWidget(row, 5, new MoneyLabel(gwinvoice.getNet()));
         table.setWidget(row, 6, new MoneyLabel(gwinvoice.getTax()));
         table.setWidget(row, 7, new MoneyLabel(gwinvoice.getGross()));
         row++;
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
         //Debugging code

        StackTraceElement[] st = cause.getStackTrace();
       String error = "get invoice list failed\n";

       error = error+cause.getClass().getName()+"\n";
       if (cause instanceof StatusCodeException){
            StatusCodeException sce=(StatusCodeException) cause;
            int sc = sce.getStatusCode();
            error=error+"Status Code:"+ sc+"\n";
        }
       for (int i=0; i<st.length; i++){
           error = error + st[i].toString()+ "\n";
       }
        Window.alert(error);
    }
};
```

The call always fails with a 500 status code and therefore triggers the OnFailure method of the AsyncCallback inner class.

I am somewhat at a loss to work out why because there is no server-side error.

> > > The problem is one of serialization on the server side, but I can't see where it's coming from. I have overridden OnAfterResponseSerialized to probe things and it isn't called - (it is called by other methods in the same service implementation class, so the probe is working). 
> > >       From the javadocs, processCall() should be throwing a SerializationException. I need to catch it and see what's going on.

Comment: GWTInvoiceList implements Serializable? has a default constructor? apply this two questions recursively to all variables declared on GWTInvoiceList.

Answer (score 0):

What does the GWTInviceList code look like?

I'm guessing you don't have a no-parameter constructor for the GWTInvoiceList class.

Comment: no it's not that `package uk.co.platosys.plataccs.shared.boox;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class GWTInvoiceList extends ArrayList<GWTInvoice> implements Serializable, IsSerializable {

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 4065179521064190133L;

 /**
  * 
  */
 

 public GWTInvoiceList() {
  
 }
}`

Comment: sorry that code didn't format very prettily. But as you can see it isn't missing a no-args constructor.

Comment: Did you also try calling super(); from that no-arg constructor?

Comment: Yes; makes no difference. The list is created on the server,

Comment: It is a problem with serialization though; it's not getting serialized on the server, OnAfterResponseSerialized isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
 /**
 * catches the SerializationException for forensic examination.
 */
@Override
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException{
    try{
        return super.processCall(payload);
    }catch(SerializationException se){
        logger.log("Xservlet serialisation excption", se);
        throw se;
    }
}
```

added to the service implementation class catches the SerializationException so I can trace the aberrant object.